# Updating session vaules in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, return-value

Have a little problem, how to update single value in CI session.

I have

```
$data['jezik'] = $this->uri->segment(1);
$this->session->userdata('jezik',$data['jezik']);
$data['jezik']= $this->session->userdata('jezik');
```

But it does not change the value. Always the same!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('jezik',$data['jezik']);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `set_userdata` rather than `userdata`.  There are two ways to do it.  You can do it in a key/value type way

```
$this->session->set_userdata('jezik', $data['jezik']);
```

Or you can pass an array

```
$sessionData = array('jezik' => $data['jezik'])
$this->session->set_userdata('jezik',$data['jezik']);
```

You can read more about CodeIgniter sessions [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Like @Pattle said

```
$this->session->set_userdata('jezik', $data['jezik']);
```

Though I think he meant to pass in the array, like so:

```
$sessionData = array('jezik' => $data['jezik']);   
$this->session->set_userdata($sessionData);
```